# Need one example deno on how to use karate scripts for peformance testing using gatling from scratch

Tags: karate

I am very new to perf testing, i went through the sample project created using karate scripts in gatling, but unable to understand how to do it,

Can anyone please provide explanation on how to use karate for performance testing using gatling by using some public api like below

Scenario: Get State specific information - one state

Given url 'http://services.groupkt.com/state/get/IND/AP'
    When method get
    Then status 200
    * def resp = response.RestResponse.result.name
    * print resp

so that we can use it in our project.  unable to understand the current demo project available in github karate

Comment: Sorry peter , i accepted it now, i am new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to Git-clone and run (using Maven) this simple, stand-alone project: https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-gatling-demo

Take the help of someone who knows their way around a Maven project if needed.

Once you get this running, you will be able to understand and modify this in no time.

```
package mock

import com.intuit.karate.gatling.PreDef._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class CatsSimulation extends Simulation {

  val protocol = karateProtocol(
    "/cats/{id}" -> Nil,
    "/cats" -> Nil
  )

  val create = scenario("create").exec(karateFeature("classpath:mock/cats-create.feature"))
  val delete = scenario("delete").exec(karateFeature("classpath:mock/cats-delete.feature"))

  setUp(
    create.inject(rampUsers(10) over (5 seconds)).protocols(protocol),
    delete.inject(rampUsers(5) over (5 seconds)).protocols(protocol)
  )

}
```

Comment: Thanks peter, I cloned sample project  and try to run using maven, but nothing is displayed in the reports and co0nsole.  I developed karate scripts for my project using eclipse maven karate project , planning to use same scripts for gatling.  it will be real helpful if we have some basic guide for starting up performance testing using karate , which explains to build up from scratch.

Comment: sorry i can not help you with such a basic question. let us hope somebody else will. there is a video link in the readme - and if you can’t figure out from that maybe this is all too advanced for you. all the best

Comment: Thanks peter, by using jenkins I am able to run this project.